# Why using an ivar can cause a retain cycle in reactive cocoa?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, reactive-cocoa, retain-cycle

I use an ivar in a reactive cocoa's block, set weakify(self) and strongify(self) to break the retain cycle. But when I run the code, It causes a memory leak, the controller doesn't call `dealloc` method. If I change the ivar to an property, it runs right. I'm so confused about it and search for a long time. please tell me why.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     ...
     @weakify(self);
     [RACObserve(self, something) subscribeNext:^(id x) {
         @strongify(self);
         [_button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
     }];
}

- (void)dealloc {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`@strongify(self)` declare new variable with name self and when you call `self.button` you use this new variable, `_button` implicitly use don't overriden self

Comment: `@weakify(self)` declare a weak self, `@strongify(self)` declare a strong self. `self.button` means to use the strong one, but `_button` does't use it. save my day.